# javascript for html scrollbar that works in firefox

Tags: javascript, css, firefox

thanx b4, I'm using css to style html scrollbar, works fine in all major browser but FireFox. I want a javascript that style HTML scrollbar and all it elements for Firefox without messing with worked IE, webkit, & opera CSS scrollbar

```
html{
scrollbar-base-color: #666666;
scrollbar-3dlight-color: #666666;
scrollbar-darkshadow-color: #666666;
scrollbar-highlight-color: #666666;
scrollbar-track-color: #ffffff;
scrollbar-arrow-color: #666666;
scrollbar-shadow-color: #666666;
scrollbar-dark-shadow-color: #666666;}

::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 18px; height: 18px;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button {  background-color: #666; }
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {  background-color: #fff;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece { background-color: #fff;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb { height: 50px; background-color: #666;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner { background-color: #666;}
::-webkit-resizer { background-color: #666;
}
```

Comment: Did you try [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference/Mozilla_Extensions) properties, `-moz-scrollbar` ?

Comment: thnx S, tried this b4-moz-scrollbarbutton-down{}
-moz-scrollbarbutton-left{}
-moz-scrollbarbutton-right{}
-moz-scrollbarbutton-up{}
-moz-scrollbar-small{}
-moz-scrollbarthumb-horizontal{}
-moz-scrollbarthumb-vertical{}
-moz-scrollbartrack-horizontal{}
-moz-scrollbartrack-vertical{}
-moz-separator{}

Comment: where {} is the same as in ::-webkit-, still wont do. Is there any javascript script can do this for firefox, try nicescroll and perfectscroll but cant figure out how to make it works with entire html

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using standard CSS instead of Webkit specific extensions?  If Firefox doesn't  support scrollbar as part of the former yet, use the Mozilla prefixed versions for their experimental implementation.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference/Mozilla_Extensions

Comment: maybe u can show me the right value(s) for -moz-scrollbar, thnx again Dan